# Vim interrupts Ex command in a plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have written a plugin that prints out a number of matches after a search command. Here is the simplest working example of this functionality:

```
map <silent> n n:call Test()<CR>
function! Test()
  let output=''
  redir => output
    %s///n
  redir END
  echo str2nr(matchstr(output, '\d\+'))
endfunction
```

However, I have observed a weird effect - when Vim cannot keep up with event processing (e.g. the file is large, and `n` key is held), it interrupts the `%s///n` command that my function uses internally. That is, `output` variable is left empty, and `Test()` prints out `0`. The same occurs if I invoke `:normal n`.

Is this behavior documented? Is it at least possible to detect that the interrupt has occured?

EDIT: For a clean repro, run `vim -u test_vimrc`, with `test_vimrc` file as follows:

```
set nocompatible                                                             
set lazyredraw                                                               
map <silent> n n:call Test()<CR>                                             
function! Test()                                                             
  let output=''                                                              
  redir => output                                                            
  %s///n                                                                     
  redir END                                                                  
  echo str2nr(matchstr(output, '\d\+'))                                      
endfunction
```

Then open any file, search for an existing text, then use `:normal n`. 0 will be printed out. This doesn't occur without `lazyredraw`; perhaps the bug is related to it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (not with a 500 KB file, nor with `:normal n`; the only way to interrupt is via `<C-C>`; Vim is single-threaded in its script execution.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have now added a full repro, which works on newest Vim (7.4.922) invoked with almost empty vimrc. It seems like it is a problem with lazyredraw.